# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given?

Tags: php, mysqli

this is the first time ever that I am trying to secure my code against sql injection using `mysqli prepared statement`. so please be gentle and explain things in simple terms so I can understand it.

Now I am using the following code which I thought i was right but it throws these errors and I do not understand that at all.

**here is the errors:**

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in on line 92

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in on line 93

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in  on line 96
```

**here is the code:**

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "INSERT $storenameTable (firstname, lastname, username, address_1, address_2, postcode,  country, county, city, email, password, storeShop, signupdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issi", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $address_1, $address_2, $postcode, $country, $county, $city, $email, $hashedPass, $storenameTable);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     <//<<<<<<<< line 92
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))     <//<<<<<<<< line 93
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  <//<<<<<<<< line 96
    //update was successful
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
}
```

i would appreciate your help.

Comment: Your `prepare()` failed.  You *need* to add error checking, and not just assume the query worked.  `if($stmt === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($db_conx)); }`.  Also, check all of the "Related" questions on the right side of this page.

Comment: `mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a missing parameter, you should have 13 parameters and 13 `?` check the two parameters after password. (I took out `signupdate`) try the below :

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "INSERT INTO $storenameTable (firstname, lastname, username, address_1, address_2, postcode,  country, county, city, email, password, storeShop) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issi", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $address_1, $address_2, $postcode, $country, $county, $city, $email, $hashedPass, $storenameTable);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     <//<<<<<<<< line 92
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))     <//<<<<<<<< line 93
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  <//<<<<<<<< line 96
    //update was successful
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
}
```

You also can get more details on the last error by using `var_dump(mysqli_error($db_conx));`

Comment: The `INTO` keyword is optional.

Comment: he has a missing parameter

Answer (score 1):

`password` is a function name in MySQL. Function names, like reserved words, must be enclosed in backticks to be used as a field name.

Personally, I'd say put backticks around all database, table and column names.

Using "bare" names in MySQL is akin to using bare strings in PHP. Sure, `$foo = bar;` will *work*, but it relies on `bar` not being a constant. Well, in MySQL, you are relying on your column names not being reserved words. Same thing. Use backticks!

Comment: This answer could be improved by explicitly stating that the failure to quote reserved words caused `mysqli_prepare` to fail, and that the return value from `mysqli_prepare` should be checked for error.

Comment: I never had to use backticks around a column name password before. If the OP had a function called `password()` I'd agree, but I doubt this is the case; unless you have actual proof of this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: I agree, but the OP isn't selecting a column from a table as per the manual `SELECT PASSWORD('mypass')`, is using inside the values; unless there's something I'm not grasping.

Comment: But `password` is a function name, regardless of where it appears ;)

Comment: I use this with no problem `$query = "SELECT username, password, salt FROM...`

Comment: -shrugs- My point about using bare field names stands. It's no better than bare strings in PHP.