# Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\update.php on line 66

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting the error above on a CRUD application that I am using. I tried the previous suggestion on this website but the problem continues. I took the code from tutorialrepublic. my code is as follows. I have been trying to solve this and have tried a lot but can't really figure out what the problem might be and need some help.

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $description = $usage = "";
$name_err = $description_err = $usage_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    
    // Validate name
    $input_name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    if(empty($input_name)){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $name_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $name = $input_name;
    }
    
    // Validate description description
    $input_description = trim($_POST["description"]);
    if(empty($input_description)){
        $description_err = "Please enter a description.";     
    } else{
        $description = $input_description;
    }
    
    // Validate usage
    $input_usage = trim($_POST["usage"]);
    if(empty($input_usage)){
        $usage_err = "Please enter a usage.";     
    } else{
        $usage = $input_usage;
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($description_err) && empty($usage_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE products SET name=?, description=?, usage=? WHERE id=?";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $param_name, $param_description, $param_usage, $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_description = $description;
            $param_usage = $usage;
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: database.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $name = $row["name"];
                    $description = $row["description"];
                    $usage = $row["usage"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Update Record</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the record.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $name_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($description_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea name="description" class="form-control"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $description_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($usage_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label>Usage</label>
                            <textarea name="usage" class="form-control"><?php echo $usage; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $usage_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
//config.php file
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'cs');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$link` get defined? What's inside of `config.php`? The error you are getting means that `$link` is probably `false` as opposed to a handle to the database. Possibly this is where `config.php` comes in, so that's why I mentioned if you code post that code too.

Comment: please find the code for my config.php                                              
 <?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'cs');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922004/warning-mysqli-stmt-bind-param-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-stmt-boolean#22922203
check this

Comment: I have already tried that but it doesn't seem to correct the error